# Solution to the Eikonal equation with almost everywhere continuous derivative

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, geometric-measure-theory

Let $\Omega$ be an open, bounded, connected subset of $\mathbb R^n$ with smooth boundary. Does there always exist an almost everywhere solution $u \in W^{1, \infty}$ to the following system of PDE?

$$|Du| = 1$$
$$\lim_{\delta \to 0_+} \text{sup}_{y, z \in B_d (x)} \,|Du(y) - Du(z)| = 0$$
$$u = 0 \text{ on } \partial \Omega.$$

*Note: We say $u \in W^{1, \infty}$ is an almost everywhere solution if the first two equations above are satisfied for Lebesgue almost every $x \in \mathbb R^n$.*

In other words, is there a Lipschitz solution to the Eikonal equation with almost everywhere continuous derivative?

Comment: Not a real answer: unless I'm mistaken there always exists a (unique) viscosity solution. Such solutions are well-known to be semi concave (or semi convex, depending on your convention for visosity solutions). And such functions are in turn a.e. twice differentiable (Alexandrov's theorem). Maybe this is enough to conclude? I'm not an expert, though...

Comment: Another important piece is the well-known fact that iviscosity solutions satisfy the equation in the pointwise sense at any point of differentiability.